# Checking the gcc version in a Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile, version, portability, compiler-warnings

I would like to use some  gcc warning switchs that aren't available in older gcc versions (eg. -Wtype-limits).

Is there an easy way to check the gcc version and only add those extra options if a recent gcc is used ?

Comment: What's wrong with `gcc --version`?

Comment: @rlibby: gcc --version or gcc -dumpversion are fine. I'm looking for a "version is greater" comparison in the Makefile.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I wouldn't say its easy, but you can use the `shell` function of GNU make to execute a shell command like `gcc --version` and then use the `ifeq` conditional expression to check the version number and set your `CFLAGS` variable appropriately.

Here's a quick example makefile:

```
CC = gcc
GCCVERSION = $(shell gcc --version | grep ^gcc | sed 's/^.* //g')
CFLAGS = -g

ifeq "$(GCCVERSION)" "4.4.3"
    CFLAGS += -Wtype-limits
endif

all:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog.c -o prog
```

**Edit:** There is no `ifgt`. However, you can use the shell `expr` command to do a greater than comparison. Here's an example

```
CC = gcc
GCCVERSIONGTEQ4 := $(shell expr `gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1 -d.` \>= 4)
CFLAGS = -g

ifeq "$(GCCVERSIONGTEQ4)" "1"
    CFLAGS += -Wtype-limits
endif

all:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog.c -o prog
```

Comment: Use `:=` instead of `=`, or else that `$(shell)` is going to get run every time `$(GCCVERSION)` is expanded.

Comment: I would like to check for greater than a certain version. Is the there a ifgt equivalent to ifeq ?

Comment: thanks - very useful - I was just about to post a question asking how to test for gcc version >= 4.3 but I worked it out myself using your `expr` method.

Comment: I fixed the reversed logic of the greater than comparison. Thanks.

Comment: I used `GCCVERS := $(shell gcc --version | grep ^gcc | awk '{print $$3}')`

Comment: Shouldn't it be ifeq "$(GCCVERSIONGTEQ4)" "0"?

Comment: Not valid for version 5.4.0, because it adds to the end the date: `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609`--> gives version 20160609 instead 5.4.0

Comment: We should be using `$(shell $(CC) -dumpversion`, since we might want to `make CC=gcc-10` or whatever.

Answer (score 23):

To transform full 3-part gcc version (not only first digit) into numerical format, suitable for comparison (e.g. `40701`) use

```
gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\.\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' -e 's/\.\([0-9]\)/0\1/g' -e 's/^[0-9]\{3,4\}$/&00/'
```

Which addresses the possibility of double-digit numbers in any of the version part, and possibility of missing 3-rd part of the version in output of `gcc -dumpversion` (which is the case in some earlier gcc versions).

So to test the version in makefile, use something like (note `$$` inside last sed command)

```
GCC_GTEQ_472 := $(shell expr `gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\.\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' -e 's/\.\([0-9]\)/0\1/g' -e 's/^[0-9]\{3,4\}$$/&00/'` \>= 40702)
ifeq "$(GCC_GTEQ_472)" "1"
  ...
endif
```

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this problem where I needed to test the first two digits of gcc and wanted a more readable option than the clever sed hackery above. I used bc to do the comparison since it supports floating point (expr treats non-integers as strings):

```
GCC_VER_GTE44 := $(shell echo `gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1-2 -d.` \>= 4.4 | bc )
ifeq ($(GCC_VER_GTE44),1)
...
endif
```

If they release gcc 4.10 after gcc 4.9, then a bit of sed hacking is necessary, but this is still pretty readable:

```
GCC_VER_GTE44 := $(shell echo `gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1-2 -d.` \>= 4.4 | sed -e 's/\./*100+/g' | bc )
ifeq ($(GCC_VER_GTE44),1)
...
endif
```

Answer (score 6):

I found this and thought it was really clever. It implements >, >=, <, and <= with fewer shell calls:

```
GCC_VERSION := $(shell gcc -dumpversion)
VERSION := 7.4.0

ifeq ($(VERSION),$(firstword $(sort $(GCC_VERSION) $(VERSION))))
    # stuff that requires GCC_VERSION >= VERSION
endif
```

This example shows >=. You can implement >, <=, or < using combinations of ifneq and $(lastword).

References:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2006-04/msg00065.html

Comment: Has been nice for over 10 years but fails with double-digit version elements... such as in GCC 10, which has already been released. Example: "9.0 8.0 10.0" is sorted into "10.0 8.0 9.0".

Comment: `sort -n` might fix that

Answer (score 2):

Are you using something like autoconf?

It might be worth invoking a 'dummy' compile via gcc with the flag enabled and if that one fails because the compiler doesn't recognise the flag, you can fall back to the command line that doesn't use the newer warning options.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a ready-to-use IF_GCC macro, based on the answers above:

```
MY_GCC_VERSION=$(if $(GCC_VERSION),$(GCC_VERSION),$(GCC_DEFAULT_VER))
MY_GCC_TOINT=$(shell echo $(1) | sed -e 's/\.\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' -e 's/\.\([0-9]\)/0\1/g' -e 's/^[0-9]\{3,4\}$$//')
MY_IF_GCC=$(if $(shell test $(call MY_GCC_TOINT, $(MY_GCC_VERSION)) -$(1) $(2) || echo 0),$(4),$(3)) 
GCC_DEFAULT_VER:=$(firstword $(shell cc -V 2>&1 | grep default | sed -r 's/( *)([0-9.]+),(.*)/\2/g'))
```

Usage: `$(call MY_IF_GCC,ge,30305,-fan_option_for_gcc_ge_3.3.5)`

As the second argument, you can use any operator of those supported by test(1): eq, gt, lt, ge, le etc.

If cc -V doesn't work for you, replace it with gcc -dumpversion or whatever suitable

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Following Chris, but using awk

```
GCC_VER_GTE44 := $(shell expr $$(gcc -dumpversion | awk -F. '{print $$3+100*($$2+100*$$1)}') \>= 40400)
```

note `$` needs to be escaped in Makefile with another `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `awk` is a better tool for this purpose, as it can both split the the version string into `$1` `$2` and `$3` and then do the comparison with `>`, `<`, `>=` etc. in one command. The whole line is omitted from `awk` output if the expression is false.

```
GCC_VERSION_GT_75 = $(shell gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion | awk -F. '$$1 > 7 && $$2 > 5')
ifneq ($(GCC_VERSION_GT_75),)
    # stuff that requires gcc version > 7.5
endif
```