# Why do these two commands give different gcc versions on my Mac?

Tags: gcc, homebrew

I had installed gcc on Mac High Sierra(as its needed for some software that I need to use). I was asked to check if my gcc was updated, in order to install the said software. Upon some searching, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188267/checking-the-gcc-version-in-a-makefile) command to find it -

`gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1,2,3 -d.`

This gives the output as 4.2.1.

When I try to run `brew install gcc`, it however says -

> Error: gcc 8.2.0 is already installed
>   To upgrade to 8.3.0, run `brew upgrade gcc`

I don't understand why these two commands give different versions of gcc installed, and which of the two could actually be getting used while I am trying to install the software. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PATH!

The first is running `/usr/bin/gcc` from XCode which gives a GCC 4.2.1 version.  The second is running the version from where `brew` installs it.  You need to fix your PATH so that the Brew (HomeBrew) `bin` directory is on your PATH before `/usr/bin`.  I [think](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ) that's `/usr/local/bin`, but you may have a different location.  (I tend to install things in oddball locations; referring to `/usr/local/Homebrew/bin` and `/usr/local/Cellar` may not help you.)

Wherever it is installed, make sure that the directory is on your `PATH` before the `/usr/bin` directory.  That may involve hacking your `~/.profile` file, or `~/.bashrc` – again, depending on how you set things up.  If you use `tcsh`, it'll be `~/.login` or `~/.cshrc` that needs editing.

You may also find `/usr/libexec/path_helper` helpful; look at the manual page for it (`man path_helper`) to see how to modify its default configuration.  Be careful how you do that, and make backups, and test (`bash -l` to simulate a login).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I did change my .bash_profile to include `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`, and activated the changes, but on running `gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1,2,3 -d.`, it still gives me 4.2.1 and on running `which gcc`, it still gives me `/usr/bin/gcc`. Any ideas what could be going wrong? I did try all this on a new instance of the terminal

Comment: Maybe `hash -r`?   Maybe run the two variants by full pathname to see that they do report different versions.

Comment: I also tried adding `alias gcc='/usr/local/bin/gcc-8'` to the .bash_profile, but that didn't work either. I am a bit hesistant about `hash -r` since it would make it forget ALL remembered locations, but I will do it if there's no other option. Didn't quite understand what you meant by your second statement

Comment: Using `hash -r` has a minimal cost.  You won’t measure it.

Comment: I tried `hash-r`, but `which gcc` still gave `/usr/bin/gcc`. However, like before, `which gcc-8` still gives `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8`. Do you think somethings up between gcc/gcc-8. Even if it is, I thought doing `alias gcc='/usr/local/bin/gcc-8'` should have resolved it

Comment: I have precisely one alias in my profile and an essentially empty bashrc.  I don’t like the confusion that aliases cause.  If I need it, it’s a script.  I have hundreds of them. Literally!  (My private bin directory has over 500 programs and scripts in it.)  if you can’t get the path to work, make symlinks `gcc-4` to `/usr/bin/gcc` and `gcc-8` to `/usr/local/bin/gcc` and use the suffixed names.  Or something along those lines.

Comment: If you're still having problems, it's going to take a good deal of data to work out what's going wrong — lists of files in directories (at least, of files with a name that matches `gcc*`), and environment, and making sure the modified PATH is exported properly, and so on.  The most relevant directories are `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. It'll turn out to be something small and silly and obvious once spotted (but mystifying until spotted).  If you're really stuck, contact me by email — see my profile.  Please include a link to this question to identify what the subject is about.

Comment: Thanks for that elaborate explanation, Jonathan. I just wanted to give a quick update. Today when I ran `gcc -dumpversion`, it actually gave me 8.2.0!!! However, running `which gcc` still gives `usr/bin/gcc`. This has made me happy and confused at the same time, since now I don't know which gcc is actually being used by default. In any case I will try what you have described above